# How to regex the search term in a URL

Tags: javascript, regex

I have urls having search terms as mentioned below:

Search term : new cars

URL:

```
https://www.google.co.in/search?q=new+cars&oq=new+car&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.340860j0j8&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8
```

Search term: jungle book & characters

URL:

```
https://in.search.yahoo.com/search;_ylt=A2oKmKEkpE1WqioAkV67HAx.;_ylc=X1MDMjExNDcyMzAwMwRfcgMyBGZyA3lmcC10LTEwMQRncHJpZANWSDhxR0pDUlJZcXNUTG1oM0JkMFBBBG5fcnNsdAMwBG5fc3VnZwM4BG9yaWdpbgNpbi5zZWFyY2gueWFob28uY29tBHBvcwMwBHBxc3RyAwRwcXN0cmwDBHFzdHJsAzI0BHF1ZXJ5A2p1bmdsZSBib29rICYgY2hhcmFjdGVycwR0X3N0bXADMTQ0NzkyODk3Nw--?p=jungle+book+%26+characters&fr2=sb-top-in.search&fr=yfp-t-101&vm=r
```

Is there a way to regex and match only the search term (which does not include the special characters) in a generic way, so that it would handle all types of search urls ?

Comment: What language are you using?  I would start with a clever regex to extract the relevant portion of the query string.  Then I would split and check each piece against the terms you want to match.

Comment: I'm not sure there is a silver bullet here, since each website you listed has a different name for its query parameters.

Comment: I tried this, but I should not capture the special character (+) : 
      (?![pq]=)([a-z+]*)(?=\&)

Comment: For Google I would use `^https://.*search\?(.*)$` to extract the query parameters.  First split the match on `=`, then split on `+` to get the terms.

Comment: What about the space char ^_^?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it finally .. here we need to look into various patterns found the search urls:
Using non-capturing groups:

```
(?:(?:[?|&][p|q]=))([^&]*)
```

https://regex101.com/r/gG6jR7/2

Not using non-capturing groups:

```
[?|&][p|q]=([^&]*)
```

https://regex101.com/r/gG6jR7/3

Comment: Why use this instead of the other, more efficient regular expressions posted by others? `p=([^&]*)` as @Jan posted works just as well. `[pq]=([^&]*)` would work for both Google and Yahoo.

Comment: Its because p is used by yahoo and q is used by google.
My regex handles both.

Answer (score 2):

- Google: `q=([^&]*)` (after `q=` match everything up to the next
  ampersand or up to the end)   Match: `new+cars`
- Yahoo: `p=([^&]*)` (same idea with `p=`)
  Match: `jungle+book+%26+characters`
- Both: `[pq]=([^&]+)` (combined, p or q)

While this might work, you'd be better of using `parse_url()` in PHP or (as your question is tagged with JavaScript) have a look at [phpjs.org](http://phpjs.org/functions/parse_url/), an equivalent of PHP functions in JS.

See this working [regex fiddle for yahoo](https://regex101.com/r/gG6jR7/1).